# How to send a message to specific user using aspnetcore signalR?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a requirement to send notification to specific user. I am using dotnet core 3.1. ASPNETCORE signalR for the notification.
I am able to send the messages to all clients but unablt to do so for specific user.

**EDIT 1**

My Hub looks like :

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
    }
}
```

And i am calling the SendAsync method from Controller as :

```
 private IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hub;

    public NotificationController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
    {
        _hub = hub;
    }

[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage",
        _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("SendMessage",
            new
            {
                val1 = getRandomString(),
                val2 = getRandomString(),
                val3 = getRandomString(),
                val4 = getRandomString()
            });

        return Ok(new { Message = "Request Completed" });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can send message to specific user via [user id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#iuserid-provider)

In this example, we will try to get current user info and send some data back to that user using user id:

In the hub:

```cs
public async Task GetInfo()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(Context.User);

    await Clients.User(user.Id).SendCoreAsync("msg", new object[] { user.Id, user.Email });
}
```

In the client:

```js
connection.on('msg', function (...data) {
    console.log('data:', data); // ["27010e2f-a47f-4c4e-93af-b55fd95f48a5", "foo@bar.com"]
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    connection.invoke('getinfo');
});
```

**Note:** Make sure you've already mapped the hub inside `UseEndpoints` method:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapHub<YourHubName>("/yourhubname");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send notifications to a specified if you know the users connectionId or add the connected user to an group.

In the hub, assuming you know the connectionId:

```cs
await this.Clients.Client("connectionId").SendAsync("MethodName", "The message");
```

You also can add a specified user in to a group and then send the message to the group:

```cs
await this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync("connectionId", "groupName");

await this.Clients.Group("groupName").SendAsync("MethodName", "The message");
```

You can read more about it in this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

**Update:**

To answer your updated question, you must provide the authorization attribute to your hub in order to have identity name and other parameters

```cs
[Authorize]
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(ex);
    }
}
```

And then on your Angular client, you must provide a token to connect to your hub like:

```js
private configureSignalR(token: string) {
    this.hubMessageConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Error).withUrl(this.signalRUrl + "/notifications",
    {
        accessTokenFactory: () => token
    })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
}
```

You can read more about [Authentication and authorization in the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: I have updated my question and shown there how am i using the Hub and its function.
 await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name);
But i am getting Context.User.Identity.Name as null. Where am i going wrong. I have my client as angular app.

Answer (score 1):

To send a message to a particular user you simply call:

```
_hubContext.Clients.User(useridentifier).SendAsync("my_message");
//_hubContext is your context, can be a DI injected variable etc
```

If you're using ASP.NET Core built-in authentication, it works out of the box as long as you have `[Authorize]` in your Hub.

**BUT!** if you're using custom authentication, like `CookieAuthetication` for example, then you have to supply a "name-provider" to SignalR, so it knows which user to put in which bucket.

Like this:

```
public class NameUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        //for example just return the user's username
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

And then register this "provider" in Startup.cs

```
//needed for SignalR to support "Context.UserIdentifier" and built-in user mapping
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a bug in ASP.NET Core SignalR (*I'm also using ASP.NET Core 3.1*),

```
_hubContext.Clients.User(userId).SendAsync(...)
```

doesn't seem to work. Note that by default `userId` is what it's stored as `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` for Claims based authentication (*From doc : By default, SignalR uses the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier from the ClaimsPrincipal associated with the connection as the user identifier.*)

So I had to create my own connection manager and it works fine, once getting all user's connections you can loop and write something like

```
_hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync(...)
```

Here is a hint for how user's connections are managed :

```
public class YourHub : Hub
        ...
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {    
            //Get userId
            _connectionHubManager.AddConnection(userId, Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            _connectionHubManager.RemoveConnection(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
```

To get `userId` depends on your implentation.

If `userId` is registred as `ClaimTypes.Name` you can simply get it :

```
Context.User.Identity.Name;
```

If `userId` is registred as `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` you need to do :

```
(Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity)?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
```

Don't forget to add `[Authorize]` to your hub class in order to get those fields filled and check [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-3.1#bearer-token-authentication) for SignalR authentication.

Comment: I have found the answer to this problem, i will update my version of answer soon.

Comment: @AkshayKumarSharma Hi, can you add your answer